# Is there a simple way in ASP.Net to get the current URL with some query parameters changed?

Tags: asp.net, query-string

I've had several cases where I had a page with several query parameters - most recently a search results page - and needed to create a link to the same page with one or more query parameters changed in the URL. This seems like such a common use case that I feel as though there must be some simple built-in way of doing it.

Right now, I'm using a function I wrote which takes in a dictionary of parameters and values and merges them with the params and values from `Request.QueryString`. Parameters given with a `null` value are removed. It works, but I'm open to simpler methods.

Comment: No, there isn't a built-in way to do it.  Merging manually (or with some existing 3rd party library) is the only way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor improvements I'd suggest:

```
//...
{
    UriBuilder ub = new UriBuilder(Request.Url);

    //...

    ub.Query = string.Join("&", parameters.Select(kv => string.Format("{0}={1}", Server.UrlEncode(kv.Key), Server.UrlEncode(kv.Value))));

    return ub.ToString();
}
```

---

*Edit*

Actually the return value should also be a `Uri` type but I didn't want to introduce any breaking changes.

Answer (score 1):

The function I'm using now:

```
public string ThisPageWithParams(IDictionary<string, string> newParameters)
{
    string url = Request.Url.AbsolutePath + "?";

    var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (string k in Request.QueryString)
    {
        parameters[k] = Request.QueryString[k];
    }
    foreach (var kv in newParameters)
    {
        if (newParameters[kv.Key] == null)
        {
            parameters.Remove(kv.Key);
        }
        else
        {
            parameters[kv.Key] = kv.Value;
        }
    }

    url += string.Join("&amp;", parameters.Select(kv => Server.UrlEncode(kv.Key) + "=" + Server.UrlEncode(kv.Value)));

    return url;
}
```